# Is there an easy example of a vector space which can not be endowed with the structure of a Banach space

Tags: banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be a real vector space.

Is there always a norm on $V$ such that $V$ is complete with respect  to this norm?

If not, is there an easy counterexample?

Comment: Here's a neat little fact: a Banach space can't have a basis of cardinality $\aleph_0$. Thus the space of polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$, for instance, has no Banach norm.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. Suppose $V$ is a normed space of (Hamel) dimension $\aleph_0$, with basis $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, \ldots \}$ say. Then $V$ is the union of a countable family of finite-dimensional subspaces, namely $\langle v_1 \rangle, \langle v_1, v_2 \rangle, \langle v_1, v_2, v_3 \rangle, \ldots$. Proper closed subspaces of a normed space are nowhere dense, so $V$ is a countable union of nowhere dense sets, and so is incomplete by the Baire category theorem.

Comment: Indeed, any vector space of infinite Hamel dimension less than $2^{\aleph_0}$ cannot be endowed with a complete norm.  (This is a stronger statement only if the continuum hypothesis fails.)  I found a proof at http://user.math.uzh.ch/halbeisen/publications/psf/hamel.ps

Comment: @Nate: I think this result goes back to Mackey, *[On infinite-dimensional linear spaces](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1945-0012204-1)*, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. **57** (1945), 155-207. (see Theorem I-1 on p. 159). Neither Halbeisen-Hungerbühler nor [this note](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2322577) they refer to mention this...

Comment: At [planetmath](http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/ABanachSpaceOfInfiniteDimensionDoesntHaveACountableAlgebraicBasis.html) and [Ask an analyst](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_analyst_2010;task=show_msg;msg=1432.0002) a one-page proof of the fact about cardinality $\mathfrak c$ was mentioned with reference to  H. Elton Lacey, [The Hamel Dimension of any Infinite Dimensional Separable Banach Space is c](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2318458), Amer. Math. Mon. 80 (1973), 298.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ in the product topology is an example. It's a completely metrisable topological vector space, but there can be no compatible norm because all neighbourhoods of 0 are unbounded.

Comment: The question didn't ask for a *compatible* norm.  I believe the Hamel dimension of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$, the same as any separable Banach space $X$ you care to name.  Therefore there is a linear isomorphism $T : \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \to X$ (not continuous with respect to the product topology) and so $||x|| := ||Tx||_X$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ that makes it into a Banach space (indeed, one which is isometrically isomorphic to $X$).

Comment: Yes, the question assumes no topolgy. Why was this accepted?

Comment: I didn't carefully read this.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal.
If $B$ is a Banach space such that the least size of a dense subset of $B$ is $\kappa$, then $B$ is of size $\kappa^{\aleph_0}$.
So the only possible sizes of Banach spaces are powers with the exponent $\aleph_0$.

As was pointed out above, every infinite dimensional Banach space has (Hamel) dimension at least $2^{\aleph_0}$.
If a Banach space has size $>2^{\aleph_0}$, then its size is actually equal to the dimension.  It follows that an infinite cardinal can only be the dimension of a Banach space if it is of the form $\kappa^{\aleph_0}$.
But there are many cardinals that are not of that form and for every cardinal $\kappa$ there is a vector space of dimension $\kappa$.

The first infinite cardinal not of the form $\kappa^{\aleph_0}$ is $\aleph_0$, 
as was pointed out above.  The next cardinal is $\aleph_1$, which is of the form 
$\kappa^{\aleph_0}$ iff the continuum hypothesis holds.
The only cardinals for which we can say for sure that they are not of the form $\kappa^{\aleph_0}$ are suprema of increasing chains of cardinals of countable length, like $\aleph_\omega$, the sup of the $\aleph_n$.

On the other hand, any two vector spaces are isomorphic iff they have the same dimension.  Also, there are vectorspaces of all dimensions.
So, the question whether a vector space has a norm that turns it into a Banach space really only asks which cardinals are dimensions of Banach spaces.

For every cardinal $\kappa$, $\ell^2(\kappa)$ is a Banach space (even Hilbert!) of density $\kappa$ and dimension $\kappa^{\aleph_0}$.
It follows that an infinite dimensional vector space is isomorphic to a Banach space if and only if its dimension is of the form $\kappa^{\aleph_0}$ for some $\kappa$.  (Actually, $(\kappa^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=\kappa^{\aleph_0}$, so $\lambda$ is of the form $\kappa^{\aleph_0}$ iff $\lambda^{\aleph_0}=\lambda$.)