# Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space. Prove that every Hamel basis of $X$ is uncountable.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, baire-category, hamel-basis

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space. Prove that every basis of $X$ is uncountable.

Can anyone help how can I solve the above problem?

Comment: What kind of basis? An algebraic basis? It's important at this point.

Answer (score 112):

It seems that the proof using the [Baire category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem) can be found in several places on this site, but none of those questions is an exact duplicate of this one. Therefore I'm posting a CW-answer, so that this question is not left unanswered.

We assume that a Banach space $X$ has a countable basis $\{v_n; n\in\mathbb N\}$. Let us denote $X_n=[v_1,\dots,v_n]$, i.e., the linear span of the first $n$ vectors.

Then we have:

- $X=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty X_n$
- $X_n$ is a finite-dimensional subspace of $X$, hence it is *closed*. (Every finite-dimensional normed space is complete, see [PlanetMath](https://planetmath.org/everyfinitedimensionalnormedvectorspaceisabanachspace). A complete subspace of a normed space is closed. See also: [Finite-dimensional subspace normed vector space is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854227/finite-dimensional-subspace-normed-vector-space-is-closed))
- $X_n$ is a proper subspace of $X$, so it has empty interior. See [Every proper subspace of a normed vector space has empty interior](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148850/interior-of-a-subspace)

So we see that $\operatorname{Int} \overline{X_n} = \operatorname{Int} X_n=\emptyset$, which means that $X_n$ is [nowhere dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set). So $X$ is a countable union of nowhere dense subsets, which contradicts the Baire category theorem.

---

Some further references:

**Other questions and answers on MSE**

- [Is there an easy example of a vector space which can not be endowed with the structure of a Banach space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74101/is-there-an-easy-example-of-a-vector-space-which-can-not-be-endowed-with-the-str)
- [Your favourite application of the Baire Category Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165696/your-favourite-application-of-the-baire-category-theorem/165738#165738)
- [Two problems: When a countinuous bijection is a homeomorphism? Possible cardinalities of Hamel bases?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180669/two-problem-on-topology)
- In the question [Cardinality of a Hamel basis of $\ell_1(\mathbb{R})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141535/cardinality-of-a-hamel-basis) you can learn even more - that the cardinality of the Hamel basis is at least $\mathfrak c=2^{\aleph_0}$.

**Online**

- [Banach spaces of infinite dimension do not have a countable Hamel basis](https://planetmath.org/banachspacesofinfinitedimensiondonothaveacountablehamelbasis) at PlanetMath
- [uncountable Hamel basis](http://at.yorku.ca/b/ask-an-analyst/2004/1666.htm#1666.0001) - post by [Henno Bradsma](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/4280/henno-brandsma) from Ask an Analyst ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20150921233631/http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_analyst_2004;task=show_msg;msg=1666.0001))
- Blog post [Uncountability of Hamel Basis for Banach Space II](https://matthewhr.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/uncountability-of-hamel-basis-for-banach-space-ii/) from Matt Rosenzweig's Blog

**Books**

- [Corollary 5.23](https://books.google.com/books?id=4hIq6ExH7NoC&pg=PA179) in Infinite Dimensional Analysis: A Hitchhiker's Guide by Charalambos D. Aliprantis, Kim C. Border.
- A Short Course on Banach Space Theory By N. L. Carothers, [p.25](http://books.google.com/books?id=pec4r3EsIiMC&pg=PA25)
- [Exercise 1.81](https://books.google.com/books?id=5BDX2NNsqR4C&pg=PA48) in Banach Space Theory: The Basis for Linear and Nonlinear Analysis by Marián Fabian, Petr Habala, Petr Hájek, Vicente Montesinos, Václav Zizler

Comment: I have found a proof that a proper subspace ofa normed space has empty interior here: http://matthewhr.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/uncountability-of-banach-hamel-basis.pdf

Comment: Can't we prove it without Baire Category Theory in other words without axiom of dependent choice

Comment: @Sushil You have a much better chance of getting some answer if you post your question as a question, not just as a comment. However, before posting such question, some clarifications are needed in my opinion. See [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22401261#22401261) for some comments.

Comment: Oh I see. But I want some clarity. Cardinality of Hamel basis(if exist) are equal does it imply AC(or ADC). If this implication is wrong I may ask Let X be an infinite dimensional Banach space. Prove that every Hamel basis of X is uncountable without Baire Category Theory.

Comment: Infact A vector space can't have countable basis and uncountable basis simultaneously. Do we really need AC here or can we prove it with Axiom of countable choice(if needed)

Comment: @Sushil: Without the axiom of choice it is consistent for a vector space to have two bases which have different cardinalities. I don't know if it consistent that one of them is well-ordered, though.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Can we also prove cardinality of Hamel bases(if exist) are equal then it implies AC.

Comment: @Sushil: [Not even remotely](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/93242/sizes-of-bases-of-vector-spaces-without-the-axiom-of-choice).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Ok but as I noticed from link mentioned by Asaf "vector space dimension is well-defined" is much weaker than DC. Hence now my question makes sense to ask: 'Prove that every Hamel basis in an infinite dimensional Banach Space of X is uncountable without Baire Category Theory assuming vector space dimension is well-defined". I think I can post it now.

Comment: @MartinSleziak http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340333

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by $X_n=[v_1,\dots,v_n]$? Do you mean the span?

Comment: @HelloWorld Exactly as you wrote, $X_n$ is the linear span of the vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$.

Answer (score 0):

One easy proof might the that following:

If possible let hamel basis of $X$ is countable and the basis is $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n,\cdots\}.$ WLOG we can assume $\|x_n\|=1.$ Now, take $x=\sum_0^\infty \frac{x_n}{2^n}$ which is not linearly combination of the above bases, but it is in $X$ by completeness of $X$, a contradiction.

Comment: How do you know that the limit you have is not in the finite linear span of your basis? or instead how do you know you can always find one such that it's not? I thought about this proof but this is where I was stucked.