# What do we call a Schauder-like basis that is uncountable?

Tags: terminology, topological-vector-spaces, schauder-basis

In a topological vector space, every Schauder basis is assumed countable, *by definition.* Supposing we drop the countability condition, we call this a [what goes here?] basis?

Comment: Ivan Singer discusses some notions in *Bases in Banach Space* Vol. 2, Chapter 17: A complete set $E$ in $X$  is an $ER$-set (Enflo-Rosenthal set) if every countable subfamily of $E$ has an ordering that is a basis of $X$. This is the analogue for unconditional bases. If the index set of a set $E$ is given a well-ordering, a notion of basis is defined and simply called a "trasfinite basis".