# Infinite-dimensional normed space meaning

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

I am reading about infinite-dimensional normed spaces but am struggling to understand the real meaning of it. Is there a simple explanation of this term?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

"Dimension" in the context of vector spaces is usually defined to be the cardinality (or number, in finite-dimensional cases) of elements in a basis of said vector space. An infinite-dimensional vector space is simply one which has no finite basis.

See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394132/examples-of-infinite-dimensional-normed-vector-spaces?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

For a vector space $V$ over the field $\mathbb{F}$ (this can be the reals or the complex numbers if you like) we define a basis to be a subset $B \subset V$ such that if $x \in V$ there exist a **unique** and **finite** number of elements $b_1, \ldots, b_n \in B$ and $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $x = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i b_i$. We say that $V$ is infinite dimensional if all such possible basis $B$ we have that $|B|$.

This is what is called a *Hamel basis* in the literature. You should be careful to not mix this up with *Schauder basis* which is often used for Banach spaces and Hilbert spaces (an orthonormal basis of a Hilbert space would be an example).