# Question about Hamel's basis.

Tags: banach-spaces

I'd like to prove that if I consider $X$ Banach space with $\dim X =\infty$, then $X$ can't have a countable Hamel's basis. Someone can give me a hint? Even a counterexample is enough. I think this can be linked with Baire's theorem about Banach's space, but I'm not really sure...
Thanks!

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217516/let-x-be-an-infinite-dimensional-banach-space-prove-that-every-basis-of-x-is). For just a hint: Otherwise $X=\cup_{n=1}^\infty F_i$ whee each $F_i$ is a finite dimensional subspace of $X$. Obtain a contradiction using Baire.

Comment: Thanks, I searched for similar questions about this, but I didn't find this one!