# Proving that there is no norm for the space of real-valued sequences making it a complete metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose I have a vector space $K$ which consists of real-valued sequences with only finitely many non-zero terms. I would like to show that there doesn't exist a norm on $K$ that would make it become a complete metric space. My technique is to use the *Baire Category Theorem*. However, I run into problems because of the generality of the theorem.
 Would anyone be kind enough to offer me some tips? thank you!

Comment: What difficulties are you facing? Baire's theorem is very good for this. Note that any finite-dimensional linear subspace of a normed space is closed and every proper linear subspace of a normed space has empty interior.

Comment: $K$ has a countable basis, and the rest is in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217516/let-x-be-an-infinite-dimensional-banach-space-prove-that-every-basis-of-x-is).