# The set of real sequences has no countable spanning set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm working through some old Harvard Math 55 problem sets, and one problem in particular has got me stumped:

> If $F$ is field, then prove that the vector space $F^\infty$ over $F$ (the space of infinite tuples or sequences) has no countable spanning set.

In the case that $F$ is countable or finite, we can show that the space spanned by a countable set is necessarily itself countable and therefore cannot span $F^\infty$, which is uncountable. However, that argument fails when the field is uncountable, since the span of even a single vector is an uncountable set. Any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: One idea ... given a countable set $C$, make a sequence $s$ that is not in the span of the countable set, which is to say is not a linear combination of any finite subset of the set. For set $T$ of $k$ vectors in the set $C$, if we pick a collection of $k+1$ new coordinates of $s$, then the $k$ vectors in $R^{k+1}$ we get from restricting $T$ to those $k+1$ coordinates can't span $R^{k+1}$, so we can choose values for those coordinates in $s$ to guarantee $s$ is not in the span of $T$. I seem to remember there is a more high-powered argument, but I can't recall it.

Comment: There is a high-powered argument for Banach spaces, which says that any basis for a Banach space is either finite or uncountable.

Comment: @Stanley: yes, that rings a bell - thanks. I found a write up of it here, after your hint: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217516/let-x-be-an-infinite-dimensional-banach-space-prove-that-every-hamel-basis-of  Of course, in this case we just have a vector space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one idea/hint for a proof by diagonalization. Given a countable set of sequences $C$, we want to make a sequence $s$ that is not in the span of $C$, which is to say $s$ is not a linear combination of any finite subset of $C$.

To do this, it is sufficient to make an $s$ such that, for each finite subset $T$ of $C$, say of size $k_T = k$, there are some $k+1$ coordinates of $s$ such that the vectors we get in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ by restricting $T$ to those coordinates do not span the vector in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ obtained by restricting $s$ to those coordinates. This guarantees that $s$ is not in the span of $T$.

No set of $k$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ can span $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$, so if we choose a set of new coordinates for each finite subset $T$ of $C$, we can choose values of $s$ on those coordinates appropriately to ensure the previous condition holds. This means we just need to set up the appropriate construction to make $s$.

Separately, there is a more well known argument that shows that no infinite dimensional Banach space can have a countable basis; see the question [Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space. Prove that every Hamel basis of X is uncountable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217516/let-x-be-an-infinite-dimensional-banach-space-prove-that-every-hamel-basis-of) In this case, we only have a vector space, so the techniques used there don't seem to apply.