# Regarding a homogeneous map on a Vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $(X,\|.\|)$ be a complex Banach space. Let $S$ be a dense subspace of $X$. Let $f:X\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a map such that $f$ is linear and bounded on $S$ and also $f$ is *homogeneous* on $X$ i.e $f(\alpha x)=\alpha f(x)$ for every $\alpha\in \mathbb{C}$ and $x\in X$.

Can we say that $f$ is continuous or linear on $X$?

I know that the Hahn Banach theorem assures the existence of  a unique linear and bounded extension to $f$ restricted to $S$. But I ask for the linearity or continuity of $f$ itself on all of $X$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: MO copy of the question: [Regarding additivity of a function](https://mathoverflow.net/q/293117).

Comment: The information about the domain of $f$ seems to be missing. Is "$f:\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$" supposed to be "$f:X\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$"?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I believe [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) gives a very reasonable advice about cross-posting - the most important point seems to be that you should like each post to the copy on other sites. Of course, you can also have a look at [other discussions about cross-posting on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-posting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $f$ is not necessarily linear or continuous. Let $X = l^2$ with elements denoted $x=(x_0, x_1, \dots)$. Consider the hemisphere $H = \{ \|x\| = 1, x_0 \ge 0\}$ and let $g : H \to \mathbb C$ be *any* function. Define $h : X \to \mathbb C$ by $h(x) = \begin{cases} g \left( \frac x {\|x\|} \right) \|x\| , & x_0 \ge 0 \\ g \left( -\frac x {\|x\|} \right) \|x\|, & x_0 < 0 \end{cases}$ and notice that it is a homogeneous, not necessarily continuous functional on $X$. Define $f : X \to \mathbb C$ as $f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x \in S \\ h(x), & x \in X \setminus S \end{cases}$. To see that $f$ is homogeneous, notice that $x \in S \iff rx \in S \ \forall r \in \mathbb \setminus \{0\}$. Notice that, in general, $f$ is neither continuous, nor linear.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have a Banach space $X$ and a dense subspace $S$ such that $X=S\oplus T$ where $T$ is not finite-dimensional.<sup>1</sup> (By $\oplus$ I mean direct sum as *vector space*.)

Since $T$ is infinite-dimensional, there is a discontinuous linear functional<sup>2</sup> $f\colon T\to\mathbb R$. Extending it by choosing $f|_S=0$ you get a linear functional defined on $X$ which is zero on $S$. So it fulfills your conditions. (It is not continuous if you take $X$ as the domain, but the restriction to $S$ is continuous. It is linear on $X$ and, consequently, also on $S$.)

---

<sup>1</sup>It is possible to find such situations. Consider $X=\ell_2$ and $S=c_0$, i.e., $S$ consists of all sequences with finite support. Hamel dimension of $S$ is $\aleph_0$, but $\ell_2$ has uncountable Hamel dimensions, since it is a Banach space. (See also: [Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space. Prove that every Hamel basis of X is uncountable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/217516))

<sup>2</sup>See also: [Discontinuous linear functional](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/99206).