# Is Hamel Basis necessarily uncountable?

Tags: linear-algebra, hamel-basis

Let $X$ be a (real or complex) infinite dimensional vector space. (Not Normed or Banach one).

Is every Hamel Basis for $X$ necessarily uncountable ?

Comment: The $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of sequences of real numbers in which almost all terms are zero is generated by the sequences that are all zero except for one value.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Post your comment as an answer. In fact I think  it's _the_ answer, up to isomorphism.

Comment: not necessarily, by example the polynomial ring, that it is also a vector space over $\Bbb R $ or $\Bbb C $, have an infinite countable basis. However if the space is complete (if it is Banach) then the basis is necessarily uncountable

Comment: Generally, no. But yes, in [the case of a Banach space](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217843/871199).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take any infinite dimensional vector space. Take a set $S$ of countably infinitely many linearly independent vectors from that vector space. Be $V$ the subspace spanned by $S$ (using finite linear combinations). Then the vectors in $S$ form a Hamel basis of $V$.

Thus $V$ has a countably infinite Hamel basis.

Note however, that in a vector space that has an uncountable Hamel basis, all other Hamel bases are also uncountable, as all Hamel bases of the same vector space have the same cardinality.