# Uncountable Hamel basis of Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, hamel-basis

I came across this problem: [Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space. Prove that every Hamel basis of X is uncountable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217516/let-x-be-an-infinite-dimensional-banach-space-prove-that-every-hamel-basis-of). The proof is absolutely correct however I was wondering if this is true for any normed space since I didn't see the use of completeness in the answer.

Comment: The version of the Baire Category Theorem they're using requires the completeness of the space.

Comment: You're right. I forgot that

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not true. Take, say, the space of all sequences $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of real numbers which are $0$ if $n\gg0$, with$$\lVert(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\rVert=\sup_n|a_n|.$$Then a Hamel basis of  space is $(e_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$, where $e_n$ is the sequence which takes the value $1$ when $n=1$ and which is $0$ otherwise.